# query that runs on particular Oracle DB versions only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have the below query which is required to run on the Oracle versions-12c,19c

```
select owner, credential_name, username from dba_credentials where credential_name = 'GLOBAL_EXTPROC_CREDENTIAL' 
union 
select owner, credential_name, username from cdb_credentials where credential_name = 'GLOBAL_EXTPROC_CREDENTIAL'
```

But this query is deployes to run across all the versions(11g,12c,19c) as metric.So if the version is 11g the query should not run,but if its 12c or 19c it should run.
Is there a way to get this done in a sql query?
Please suggest.Thanks.

I have tried to use below query ,but didnt work as expected.

```
with ver as
  (select distinct substr(version, 1, 2) version
   from product_component_version
  )
select owner, credential_name, username  
From (select owner, credential_name, username from dba_credentials where credential_name = 'GLOBAL_EXTPROC_CREDENTIAL' 
union 
select owner, credential_name, username from cdb_credentials where credential_name = 'GLOBAL_EXTPROC_CREDENTIAL')
where exists (select null from ver where version != '11');
```

Comment: Yes, use PL/SQL and dynamic (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) SQL for the queries. If a dictionary object isn't present or has fewer columns in a lower version, you can't have a hard dependency on those names.

Comment: Can you adapt [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552301/409172) to your previous question to this question? The DBMS_XMLGEN trick should work as long as the columns returned are the same type.

Comment: @JonHeller i have given it a go..but unsuccessful.

Comment: @RoshniRabi On the 11g version, should the query return nothing at all, or should it return just the first half of the query that uses DBA_CREDENTIALS?

Comment: @JonHeller the query should return nothing at all if the version is 11g.the views DBA_CREDENTIALS and cdb_credentials  does not exist in 11g,so if the query runs it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query uses DBMS_XMLGEN to run a different version of the query depending on the version of the database.

I've tested this query on 11.2 XE, 19 EE, and 23 free developer edition. But the query assumes the user has relatively high privileges and can view DBA* views.

```
--#4: Get the results from the XMLType.
select owner, credential_name, username
from
(
    --#3: Convert the XML to an XMLType.
    select xmltype(xml_clob_results) xmltype_results
    from
    (
        --#2: Convert the SQL to XML.
        select dbms_xmlgen.getxml(v_sql) xml_clob_results
        from
        (
            --#1: Use data dictionary to create SQL statement based on which views exist.
            select
                case
                (
                    select count(*)
                    from all_views
                    where owner = 'SYS' and view_name = 'CDB_CREDENTIALS'
                )
                when 1 then
                    q'[
                        select owner, credential_name, username from dba_credentials where credential_name = 'GLOBAL_EXTPROC_CREDENTIAL' 
                        union 
                        select owner, credential_name, username from cdb_credentials where credential_name = 'GLOBAL_EXTPROC_CREDENTIAL'
                    ]'
                else
                    '
                        select cast(null as varchar2(4000)) owner, cast(null as varchar2(4000)) credential_name, cast(null as varchar2(4000)) username
                        from dual
                        where 1 = 0
                    '
                end v_sql
            from dual
        )
    )
    where xml_clob_results is not null
)
cross join xmltable
(
    '/ROWSET/ROW'
    passing xmltype_results
    columns
        owner varchar2(4000) path 'OWNER',
        credential_name varchar2(4000) path 'CREDENTIAL_NAME',
        username varchar2(4000) path 'USERNAME'
);
```

Comment: The above runs fine in 12c and 19c,but in 11g it throws the below error--> ORA-19206: Invalid value for query or REF CURSOR parameter ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN",

Comment: @RoshniRabi What's the precise version of your 11g? Maybe the LISTAGG doesn't work if you're running 11.1.

Comment: Its being run in Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: @RoshniRabi OK, I see the problem now - not even the DBA_ view exists in 11g. But DBMS_XMLGEN can't work on NULL, so I'll need to create a fake query for 11g. I should be able to build that some time today.

Comment: @RoshniRabi Check the new version. You'll need to test carefully as there are a lot of different versions and privileges involved with this query.

Comment: The modified query works perfectly on all the version i have tested.Thanks a lot again for your help :)